# Server is not able to receive the text from client java

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am creating an app in which client can send some text to server on button click.I want to print that text on console server side,but whenever client side button is pressed nothing happens.

and after sometimes i got this line on console `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText@b2253390`. 
I am not getting why this is happening ?

**SERVER CODE :**

```
public static ServerSocket server = null;
public static Socket client = null;

public static void main(String []arg)throws IOException{
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(8002); 
        System.out.println("Server Started..............."); 
        while(true){
        client = server.accept();
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        String msg = in.readLine(); 
        System.out.println("and: "+msg); 
        }
    }catch(IOException r){
        System.out.println("error :"+r.getMessage()); 
    }
}
```

**CLIENT CODE:**

```
public void send(){
    send.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Socket cs = null;
                    try {
                        cs = new Socket("192.168.1.100", 8002);
                        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());
                        out.writeBytes(text.toString());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(KeyboardActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `text` is an `EditText`.

I think you actually meant,

```
out.writeBytes(text.getText().toString());
```

Instead of,

```
out.writeBytes(text.toString());
```